# ffmpeg lens correction, fisheye effect

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to remove fish eye effect using command line. I've found 2 ways. The simplest is using frei0r plugin called "defish0r" it has few parameters like 
fisheye type, scalling, interpol and video aspect. The second way is using ffmpeg with built-in lens correction filter (http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#lenscorrection). The second way according to documentation needs camera calibration file e.g from opencv, it might be more adequate result when you calibrated camera. My question is, what is better ? Is built-in lens correction filter is not proper way to remove fish eye effect?  When use what?

Comment: related: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14772/correct-lens-distortion-with-ffmpeg

Comment: When its about fisheye what might be better? lenscorrection or defish0r, what about camera's calibration advantages? Maybe its trivial or something, but It drives me crazy, I can't find unambiguous answer/explanation on internet

Comment: I assume it's the same procedure, but I'd like to have some docs too :) Might be a good idea to find the developer and ask him directly - when I have time I'll searching for it again. Please keep me posted :)